# How to Get Special Prices to Show with Original Price Strike-through in magento 2

Tags: magento2, discount, special-price

Am adding special price with Original Price Strike-through

Comment: Do you want to show this on which page?

Comment: In prodcut page

Answer (score 0):

to get product special price, you can use this code.

```
protected $_productRepository;

public function __construct( 
    \Magento\Catalog\Model\ProductRepository $productRepository,
) {
    $this->_productRepository = $productRepository;
}

public function getSpecialPriceById($id)
{
    $product = $this->_productRepository->getById($id);
    return $product->getSpecialPrice();
}

}
```

Now from phtml you need to call function like this one.

```
$id = 32;
echo $block->getSpecialPriceById($id);
```

Comment: any free plugin is there to do this?

Comment: You can search, if you found that one.
 If above answer help you please accept and upvote, so it can be help other in community.